# Workflow does not execute all parallel actions (Nintex)

Tags: workflow, document-set, delete

Workflow does not execute all parallel actions
Dear community,

I am quite new to work with Nintex and so is my company. I could not get any support from my company so I try my luck here.

We have multiple folders where different groups have a certain access to. To be sure that every folder contains the same information we are working with workflows to copy, update and delete the documents. We have to run the action as workflow owner, because not everyone has sufficient rights to delete it from every folder.

The copy and update process works fine so far, but I am facing some issues with the delete process.

On the first look it looks fine, and sends a confirmation mail as intended.

It is the same for all branches. The only branch it works is for the first one. All other operations are not working. To verify it a added an notification after each delete operation. I get a notification from every branch which tells me that it has run through. I also tried to make inline operations rather than parallel but did not help.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thank you very much in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: Which action are you using to delete documents?